# How can I use the ExportLogic command in EWL to deploy an application?

Tags: c#, deployment, enterprise-web-library

What exactly are the steps to take after running ExportLogic in the Package Manager Console? Does this do anything for updating the database on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy an EWL system using `ExportLogic`, the first step is to do a **release** build of your solution.

When that's done, run `ExportLogic`, which creates a `Logic Packages` folder in your solution's folder. `Logic Packages` will contain:

- `Server Side Logic` folder - contains the files you need to put on the server for your system to run correctly, minus installation-specific config files
- `Client Side Application` folder (if your system contains a client-side app) - contains the files needed to correctly run your system's client-side app, minus installation-specific config files

Copy the contents of `Server Side Logic` to your server, then create an `Installation` folder inside the `Configuration` folder and put your installation-specific config files in it.

If your system has a database, execute the portion of `Configuration\Database Updates.sql` that has not already been executed against your live database.

Finally, for each web application folder you copied to the server, create an IIS web site or virtual directory pointing to it.

If you're interested in automating some/all of these steps, there are APIs within EWL that may help.